# Is a function whose image is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ onto?

Tags: complex-analysis

As part of a question I have proved that:
if f is nonconstant and entire

for all $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ and for all $\varepsilon > 0 $ there exists $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(z) - \omega| < \varepsilon $ and that therefore, $f(\mathbb{C})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

The last part asks whether f is necessarily onto in this case.

Any hint on how start with this is appreciated.

Comment: are there further condition on $f$? If it is an arbitrary function $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, the answer is very easily no. But if $f$ is continuous/holomorphic/something-nice, it becomes more interesting.

Comment: In general the answer is now. Just consider a function that maps a number with rational real part to itself, and all with irrational real part to $0$. Do you have any further information on $f$?

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning this. I have added the details. The function is also nonconstant and entire

Comment: Is the exponential function onto?

Comment: Hint: non-constant polynomials are onto. What non-constant, non-polynomial entire functions have you come across? Which ones are onto?

Comment: Non-constant polynomials over $\Bbb C$ are indeed onto; that's the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Comment: @Greg: sorry: typo. Now fixed. But irrelevant as another hint has given the game away.

Comment: $e^z$ is entire and one-to-one but $e^z=0$ has no complex solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the (little) Picard theorem: the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem

No, $f$ does not need to be onto. But there is at most one point in $\mathbb{C}$ which is not reached by $f$.

Comment: I did not know you added the same answer already. :-)

Comment: happens to me all the time :)

Answer (score 1):

As Little Picard Theorem states, such a function is either onto or just missing one point.

$f(z)=e^z$ misses $0$ only in its range.